# Input text field size not increasing using in asp.net MVC 5 bootstrap 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to increase the width of textbox(input) which has applied **bootstrap 3** styling in my project.
The size is increasing in the [Link](http://www.codeply.com/go/EL7afg8uLE) but when I try to run this code in Visual Studio designer it is nor increasing the width of the text box.

Comment: How are you using the html designer with a mvc project? Do you mean the page inspector?

Comment: I am simply creating a view(Razor) in visual studio 2013 editor. The same code works fine in codeply(just to test) but not working as I am not getting the increased width for the textbox using visual studio designer.

Comment: What _Visual studio designer_ ? Razor does not have a visual designer. There is the page inspector and the browser.

Comment: I am using Page Inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a default Asp Mvc web project they add a default stylesheet file in the Content/ folder called Site.css

This file has the style

```
input,
select,
textarea {
   max-width: 280px;
}
```

This is for the horizontal form in the default t4 templates.

If you remove that it should work as expected